# I want to increase the KVM root file system from 60GB to 160 GB

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt

The KVM image file 3.1GB in the file system on the hypervisor. The file systems are only showing up at 60 GB with df -kh total space. I want to increase the KVM volume space to 120 GB. I tried 'virsh blockresize'. It says its unsupported?

file format: qcow2
virtual size: 160G (171798691840 bytes)
disk size: 3.0G
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
compat: 1.1
lazy refcounts: true
refcount bits: 16
corrupt: false

How do I increase the KVM volume space size so I can increase root and allocate other logical volumes/file systems.

Comment: Please show exactly what you did instead of a vague description.

Comment: You don't need to increase the file size. Instead, the filesystem inside the VM has to be modified. But, as Michael already has been written, please tell us more.

Comment: The image size in /var/lib/libvirt/images is showing 3.1G. The qemu-img info size is showing 160 GB for the virtual size. A df -kh is showing a 60 GB file system. I want to add 100 gb to the root volume so I can increase the root file system size to 120 GB. I need to know how I do that. I have tried google fu to find the answer. I haven't found it.

Answer (score 0):

Your output from qemu-img above shows the disk image exposed to the guest already offers '160 GB', of which the guest OS has only written data into 3 GB.

So if your guest OS is only reporting '60 GB' free, it suggests the problem lies in the way the guest OS is using the disk. Likely either the guest partition table layout needs to be extended or filesystem needs to be extended, or both.